# radiobutton issue

Tags: javascript, struts

I created a radio button using html tags like the following,

```
<input type="radio"
       value="NO"
       class="check"
       name="courseType"
       <%="NO".equals(request.getParameter("courseType"))?"checked=\"checked\"":""%>
       onchange="submitForm()"/>
<label for="normal">Normal</label>
```

now it is working fine.Here i want to implement same scenario using struts1.2

Note: while clicking on radio button i need to submit form and it should be checked (`<%="NO".equals(request.getParameter("courseType"))?"checked=\"checked\"":""%>` )

here i am created using struts like the following way

```
<html:radio property="courseType"
            value="FE"
            onchange="subminForm()"
            styleClass="check" />
<label for="normal">Normal</label>
```

But how could i submit and checked the radio button...?

Comment: Should this be tagged JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem or not, but you've got a typo in `onchange="subminForm()"`. Incidentally, why do you want to submit the form when a radio button selection changes? It seems like an odd user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use struts tag libraries to solve this problem, where you will use bean to store the state of the radio button. And check the state in the struts action class.